# Can we register server event handler using jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, button, handler

I have a  button server  control in my asp.net webform .

So in my webform the button has a server event handler . I want to fire the event only if the user  adds a remark in a dialog box that pops up onclient click .

So in the EditRemark() jquery function , after the user edits a remark, I want to register the server handler event handler of the button control and invoke it.

Wondering if thats' possible or if there is a work around for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with clicking your button from jquery, which should call your event handler, like this:

```
$('#button_id').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson, but my question is how to register the click event  handler before invoke it...